# how to disable button when dataSnapshot updates automatically?

Tags: java

i am retrieving children count in Firebase Realtime Database, but something unexpected happens which my retrieving code inside the button runs before i touch with my finger. Where do i need to change the button method to enable it only when i touch?

this is for a button code, retrieving children count. I've been searching and don't know where is the problem and this code always runs when dataSnapshot is updated, even though I haven't touched it

```
private void checkDuplicate() {
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   


                if (uid != null) {                        
                    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                            for (DataSnapshot u : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                int allHistoryCount = (int) u.child("history").getChildrenCount();

                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "retrieve children count under all history: " + allHistoryCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Where you call checkDuplicate() methode

Comment: before calling to checkDuplicate()  give reference id to 'myButton' as
    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonidfromxml);

Comment: @Rathnayake from onCreate()

Comment: @TejpalBh same, not work :-(